# JQuery .click() not work on Safari

Tags: jquery, safari, click

i have a hidden input and i activate this with the follow script

```
$('#portada-button').click(function(event) { 
  $('#portada-input').click();
});
```

works in all browsers except on safari. help!

Comment: How can you click on a hidden input?

Comment: Do you mean `type="hidden"` or CSS `display: none`?

Comment: @Barmar in both the cases clicking isn't possible, right?

Comment: @AmitJoki Right, but the solutions are different.

Answer (score 0):

While this might work in Firefox and Chrome, you can't force a click a hidden input in some browsers (e.g. IE).

A quick hack would be to make the input visible and assign it a class along the lines of:

```
.magic-fix {
    width:1px;
    height:1px;
    opacity: 0.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```